# Insert matrix element into a Function input in Matlab

Tags: matlab, function, input, matrix

I want to make a function that can take a matrix element as an input. Is this possible?
I have in the main script a matrix like:

```
A = [0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8]
```

I want to make a function that is like:

```
function [a] = myFunction(b, A(7))
a = b + A(7)
```

Is this possible? The error is that I have unbalanced parenthesis or brackets so I guess it doesn't like the A(7) on the input.

Any ideas? Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To do that you simply need to declare your function as you normally would

```
function [a] = myFunction(b, c)
a = b + c;
```

and provide `A(7)` as an input: `result=myFunction(b,A(7));`.